# defer async атрибуты загрузки скрипта

Tags: javascript

Привет .

```
<head>
<script src="1.js" async="async"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<p>content</p>
```

1.js

```
console.log(   $("p").length  )
```

Элементов не  будет найдено поскольку скрипт выполнится до отрисовки DOM .
Если использовать

```
<script src="1.js" defer></script>
```

То в консоле будет доступ к DOM.

В чём разница между выполнением скрипта при событии **DOMContentLoader**, использование атрибута **defer** со вставкой в `<head>`   и подключением скрипта в конец `<body>` ?

defer == DOMCONTENTLOADER ?

**Вопрос про порядок загрузки скриптов**

Первое — браузер гарантирует, что относительный порядок скриптов с `defer` будет сохранён.

То есть, в таком коде (с async) первым сработает тот скрипт, который раньше загрузится:

```
<script src="1.js" async></script>
<script src="2.js" async></script>
```

А в таком коде (с defer) первым сработает всегда 1.js, а скрипт 2.js, даже если загрузился раньше, будет его ждать.

```
<script src="1.js" defer></script>
<script src="2.js" defer></script>
```

Но на практике у меня это с атрибутом **async** не потверждается

1.js

```
for(var i =0;i<1000000000;i++){
    j++
}

console.log('finish 1.js');
```

2.js

```
for(var i =0 ;i<800;i++){
    j++
}
console.log('finish 2.js');
```

Файл 2.js по идее должен **подгрузится** раньше и выполнится тоже
но у меня в консоле результ

```
 finish 1.js
 finish 2.js
```

Answer (score 2):

На вашем примере этого видно не будет, потому что каждый файл это не отдельный модуль или поток,  это программный код и выполняться он будет в определенном порядке (загрузки), а не параллельно ... п.э. ожидать что 2.js отработает раньше 1.js нельзя.

Далее...
Скрипты подключают в конце `<body>`, что бы загрузка оных не задерживала от рисовку самой страницы. Отсюда и разница ...

Comment: А можете представить пример где это будет видно ?

Comment: Ну попробуйте загрузить 1.js в 10000 строк и 2.js в пару строк не с локальной машины ... результат думаю увидите ...